# Quickblox: iOS sdk return error on sending even when message is sent

Tags: ios, quickblox

I am using iOS SDK 2.2.4

I am sending message using the method

```
- (BOOL)sendMessage:(QBChatMessage *)message sentBlock:(void (^)(NSError *error))sentBlock;
```

Sometimes, the sent block returns an error (NSCocoaErrorDomain, 50X), but the message is received by recipient. 
Once this starts happening, it happens for all messages continuously.

Logging in again fixes the problem.

This is a problem for me because I am showing the error/sent status to user.

Can anyone suggest a workaround/fix for this issue?

Comment: Can you print and post 'error' instance

Comment: As I remember, it was 503 error code with text 'Service unavailable, Try again later'. I'll post exact error object when I get it next time.

Comment: Is this information enough for now?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use

```
chatDidNotSendMessage:toDialogID:error:
```

and

```
- (void)chatDidNotSendMessage:(QBChatMessage *)message error:(NSError *)error;
```